# AngularJS and jquery-ui

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I have tried to compbine angularJS and jquery-ui the last hours but with no success. I have created the real simple example at fiddle:

[My Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fk6b3mr3/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);
```

The problem is the 'ui' dependency injection but I don't know how to solve this issue. I would need jquery-ui necessarily  because of reordering table rows.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is not an Angular module/dependancy. Therefore, trying to inject it through DI is not going to work. However the inclusion of the script tag for the jQuery UI does include it into your global scope to use.

Your syntax, however, is correct if you are going to use `ui-router` or `ngAnimate`.

If you are looking for a sortable table solution for angular you can look into a few resources all which *can* be injected via the aforementioned syntax:

- [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)
- [ng-sortable](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was confused because some examples use ui, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/SSSUUUSSS/Bsusr/1/

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept if this solved your problem :)